# JavaScript can't draw after prompt

Tags: javascript, animation, setinterval, prompt

I am animating with HTML canvas and javascript via a call to `setInterval(draw,interval)`. The interval is set to 10 (which I think is 10mils, but I'm not sure!) and here is the draw method:

```
function draw()
{
    clear();
    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<nodes[i].length;j++){
            drawNode(nodes[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

function clear(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
}

function drawNode(node){
     var x=node.getX();
     var y=node.getY();
     ctx.lineWidth=5;
     ctx.strokeStyle='black';
     ctx.strokeRect(x,y,nodeWidth,nodeHeight);
     if(node.isSource()&&sinkNotFound) ctx.fillStyle='yellow';
     else if(node.isSource()&&!sinkNotFound) ctx.fillStyle='orange';
     else if(!node.isTraversable()) ctx.fillStyle='black';
     else if (node.isOpen()) ctx.fillStyle='green';
     else if(node.isDiscovered()) ctx.fillStyle='red';
     else ctx.fillStyle='white';
     ctx.fillRect(x+ctx.lineWidth,y+ctx.lineWidth,
                  nodeWidth-2*ctx.lineWidth,nodeHeight-2*ctx.lineWidth);
}
```

I also have a button, and the `onclick` for the button is defined as `askForSource()`. Here is the method:

```
function askForSource(){
    var goodInput = false;
    while (!goodInput) {
        if (state == 0) {
            var x = prompt("Source x: ", "x gride squares from the left");
            var y = prompt("Source y: ", "y gride squares from top");
            if (nodes[y][x].isTraversable()) {
                console.log('good source');
                state = 1;
                nodes[y][x].makeSource();
            }
            else alert('Invalid source');
        }
    }
}
```

The draw method is calling every 10 as I want before clicking on the button. But if I click on the button, then after I enter the information into the two prompt boxes the draw method is not called any more. I'm not sure how to make sure that the draw method keeps getting called after giving the correct input. To be clear, the draw method is not dependent upon the `state` variable. The `state` variable is only used to allow the user to click the setSource button, which I only want to allow once per use.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Are you sure draw() stops being called? Maybe something in askForSource() modifies the `nodes` array? Put a console.log statement that just prints the timestamp or something in draw().

Comment: Maybe try calling draw at the end of asForSource() BTW, yes 10 in setInterval is 10 ms, but you should use window.requestAnimationFrame(draw), the last one only calls the next function, if it can draw something on the screen.

Comment: I am sure that draw() is not called after I input through the prompt box. I'm actually using `console.log('drawing');` to see when the draw() method is being called. It is called before I input but not after.

Comment: Also, calling draw() at the end of askForSource() does not fix the problem. :( I have heard before that using window.requestAnimationFrame(draw) is a more efficient animation method, but I don't know how to use it and, quite frankly, I don't have the time to learn right now.